# Spring boot native configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to migrate existing spring boot application to spring native. In this case, I have `application.properties` and `application-dev.properties`.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import com.test.RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor;

@SpringBootApplication(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class TestApplication {

    @Value("${rest.template.connect.timeout}")
    private Integer CONNECT_TIMEOUT;

    @Value("${rest.template.connect.request.timeout}")
    private Integer CONNECT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT;

    @Value("${rest.template.read.timeout}")
    private Integer READ_TIMEOUT;

    @Value("${rest.template.max.conn.per.route}")
    private Integer MAX_CONN_PER_ROUTE;

    @Value("${rest.template.max.conn}")
    private Integer MAX_CONN;

    @Value("${slow.rest.template.read.timeout}")
    private Integer SLOW_READ_TIMEOUT;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return getRestTemplateWithTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
    }

    @Bean("slowRestTemplate")
    public RestTemplate slowRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return getRestTemplateWithTimeout(SLOW_READ_TIMEOUT);
    }

    private RestTemplate restTemplate(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
            interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        interceptors.add(new RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
        return restTemplate;
    }


    private RestTemplate getRestTemplateWithTimeout(Integer readTimeout) {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getRequestFactory(readTimeout);
        return this.restTemplate(requestFactory);
    }

    private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getRequestFactory(Integer readTimeout) {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getConnectionSettings();
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
        return requestFactory;
    }

    private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getConnectionSettings() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(MAX_CONN_PER_ROUTE);
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAX_CONN);
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
                new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                        HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager).build());
        requestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(CONNECT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        return requestFactory;
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableRetry
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Config.java

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${environment_region}.properties")
public class Config {

  private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

  public String get(String key) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    ConfigurableEnvironment env = context.getEnvironment();
    if (!map.containsKey(key) || map.get(key) == null) {
      map.put(key, env.getProperty(key));
    }
    String propertyValue = map.get(key);
    context.close();
    return propertyValue;
  }
}
```

After building image using

`./mvnw package -Pnative -DskipTests`

when I am running the application, I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'rest.template.connect.timeout' in value "${rest.template.connect.timeout}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:936) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1330) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedFieldResolver.resolve(InjectedFieldResolver.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedElementResolver.resolve(InjectedElementResolver.java:35) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.InjectedElementResolver.invoke(InjectedElementResolver.java:53) ~[na:na]
        at com.oyo.boltkeeper.ContextBootstrapInitializer.lambda$registerBoltKeeperApplication$6(ContextBootstrapInitializer.java:15) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar$ThrowableFunction.apply(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:294) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aot.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionRegistrar.lambda$instanceSupplier$0(BeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:115) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[na:na]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

What is the way to pass the configuration in spring boot native application? Or there is different way? Is something wrong being done here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to post a simple comment: my answer is not complete...

First I think you should drop the notion of profile, it is recommended in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#aot-bean-factory-preparation). Also, the concept of profile is contrary to the Ahead Of Time compilation. If you still want to, the documentation suggests to explicitly specify your active profiles in a configuration file. I guess with `spring.profiles.active=default,dev` for example.

On the other hand, I think you should specify on the command line the path of the configuration file with this option: `--spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties`.
See [this other documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config).

In an "enterprise" context, we don't include the configuration file in the .jar executable: the configuration is externalized. So I think that with a native image it's always the case.

Don't hesitate to share your solution if you find one

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I definitely provide a direction. Right now, occupied with other tasks. I will give it a try.